# $_GET removes some characters(+) and breaks my encryption key

Tags: php

How can I get the $_GET to the full string back ? It breaks my encyption key so I can't encrypt my stuff using `opnessl_public_encrypt`

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
$key = wordwrap($key, 65, "\n", true);
$key = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
$key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;
```

Original key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgrYDLP5THYt/if+wbShGksfKjmuTe7aI4UuOHNKuONT4ROdWxfN7nn1VH3gHekYDtBRkmSmMwCQLeDzzCBP+hKT0rcfypPf6oKUlzvslOcUxOT/NPElVV7O/zPulO1kIWVHls2o3ioob8r2Bh0dFTDwj6qceTe4SaAFsPN1nSVF/w2dv53ZIO3zwXLdFHJ8dzRW25eHiWTgaIWXk4nmWcwkAE49LcfcAwXWC/Q2nd4zP3uKbi4naacqMpNj5vUPmoJg7iKodrMY4v58dmmACuMqjHjgkQeMRPQK9AV7yaMx82fhUqjA+Dx396CPTCzpk6NDSN6GDKxRzIZS5jgYyfQIDAQAB
```

Key that `$_GET` gets:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgrYDLP5THYt/ifwbShGksfKjmuTe7aI4UuOHNKuONT4ROdWxfN7nn1VH3gHekYDtBRkmSmMwCQLeDzzCBP hKT0rcfypPf6oKUlzvslOcUxOT/NPElVV7O/zPulO1kIWVHls2o3ioob8r2Bh0dFTDwj6qceTe4SaAFsPN1nSVF/w2dv53ZIO3zwXLdFHJ8dzRW25eHiWTgaIWXk4nmWcwkAE49LcfcAwXWC/Q2nd4zP3uKbi4naacqMpNj5vUPmoJg7iKodrMY4v58dmmACuMqjHjgkQeMRPQK9AV7yaMx82fhUqjA Dx396CPTCzpk6NDSN6GDKxRzIZS5jgYyfQIDAQAB
```

Some characters like + gets removed from the string, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Post your code! And describe exactly whats not working and what you expect to be!

Comment: You are probably not url encoding your `+` in URLs. And your edit still doesn't show any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never ever send an encription key via GET. Use POST, and HTTPS where possible. Also, since GET variables are in the URI, some characters will get removed. Again, to avoid this, use POST.

Comment: Using POST doesn't help that much. The real problem is that they should be URL encoded

Comment: When sending non-standart character strings, yes it does. POST can handle much bigger strings and non-standard characters, while GET has many limitations.

Comment: There is no need for security for what I do, there is no https, it's to send a packet to a minecraft plugin to allow me to test my listener.

Answer (score 3):

You should not pass that character inside an url. Use [`urlencode()`<sup>Ref</sup>](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php)

```
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
```

### Considering your edit

You can simply do (**discouraged**):

```
$key = str_replace(' ','+',$_GET['key']);
```

Comment: I want to downvote it after your suggestion to replace spaces with `+`. Fix the problem, don't patch it

Comment: @JuanMendes: compeltly agree with you, that's why I wrote discouraged :). I will bold now